# Ioslides_presentation not picking up custom css on runtime shiny_prerendered

Tags: css, r, shiny, r-markdown, ioslides

I am creating an Ioslides_presentation with rmarkdown. For a very good reason, I have changed the runtime option in the YAML header from shiny to shiny_prerendered. However, I have noticed that after doing this, the output does not pick up my custom css option in the YAML header.

IE, this YAML header works and picks up the CSS fine.

```
title: "Transformers"
author: "StarScream"
runtime: shiny
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
  incremental: true
  widescreen: true
  css: foo.css
  logo: Decepticons.png
  self_contained: false
```

But this YAML header does not pick up the css (after changing runtime).

```
title: "Transformers"
author: "StarScream"
runtime: shiny_prerendered
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
  incremental: true
  widescreen: true
  css: foo.css
  logo: Decepticons.png
  self_contained: false
```

Can anyone help me with this issue, please?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS must specifically be in a folder called CSS in the root directory when using the shiny_prerendered runtime.

More details in the last section here:
https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny_prerendered.html#External_Resources